# For a c++ set, what is set.size()&1?

Tags: c++

here is the code and it returns "IGNORE HIM!" when the size is odd

```
#include <set>
std::set<char> s;
int main(){
    char c;
    while(std::cin>>c)s.insert(c);
    std::cout<<(s.size()&1?"IGNORE HIM!":"CHAT WITH HER!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: returns whether last bit is set to 1.

Comment: To have any hope of learning C++ in a reasonable amount of time you're going to have to [get and read a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The operators, what they do and how to use them will be covered in the early chapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already noticed the pattern, i.e. `set.size()&1` is true when the size is odd.

Doing a bitwise-and (`&`) on a number will set all the bits to 0, except for the last bit, if it's 1. The last bit is only 1 when the number is odd.

e.g.

```
  101100  // even
& 000001
= 000000  // false


  101101  // odd
& 000001
= 000001  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

`i & 1` is the same as `i % 2 != 0`, so it's checking if the number is odd, but in an obfuscated way. Don't do that. Your compiler knows how to optimize such things already.

Comment: Why do you call it "obfuscated"? IMHO `i & 1` is just as clear as `i % 2 != 0`, if not more, and it is also nice and short.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it maybe clear for you, but not for everyone, including OP. If it were just as clear, we wouldn't have this question, would we?

Comment: Neither is clear if you don't know what the `&` and `%` operators do. Once you know what those operators do I believe they are equally clear. I'll bet the next question from OP will be "what does the `%` operator do in C++".

Answer (score 1):

That is not a language nor container specific operation.
That is a typical operation to know if an integer is ODD or EVEN,
performing the bitwise and operation for the bit 1 will only be true in ODD integers.

```
int odd=3; //binary 011
int even=4; //binary 100

if (odd&1)
   printf ("odd number");
if (!(even&1))
   printf ("even number");
```